# Activity Indicator Not start Animating when the view controller is navigate to another view controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I currently starting the activity indicator before pushing another view controller but it is not start animating the activity indicator.

```
[activityindicator startanimating];

[self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:viewcontroller animated:YES];

[activityindicator stopanimating];
```

Comment: I think push animation is too quick to show the animation and you immediately stop it. Hence you are not able to notice it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a NSThread as call a selector as follows :

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];  
// Some code  
[spinner stopAnimating];  
[self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:viewcontroller animated:YES];
```

threadStartAnimating :

```
-(void)threadStartAnimating:(id)data  
{  
[spinner startAnimating];  
}
```

Comment: Doing this (well, with dispatch_async and a default priority queue) worked for me, but I'm not sure why that is. Nitish, any idea why your solution works?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;    

[self performSelector:@selector(navigatetodeals) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];

}
-(void)navigatetodeals
{

    yourViewController *d = [[yourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourView" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a performSelectorInBackground or something. Because you use the calls in 1 method, the UI doesn't get the chance to update therefor you do not see the activityindicator.

So for your case:

```
[activityindicator startanimating];  [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:viewcontroller animated:YES];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(stopAnimating) :nil];
```

then create a method like:

```
-(void)stopAnimating
{
[activityindicator stopanimating];
}
```

You could use a sleep or something (like sleep(1)) to show the activityindicator because just showing them when you push a view won't do it, because its done in no-time...

Hope this helps!