# activity indicator on uialertview

Tags: iphone, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a time-consuming step to be done, if the user clicks on a certain button on an uialertview. I would like to notify the user with an activity indicator while its being done. Im not sure what exactly needs to be done for the desired output. Here is the flow:

User clicks on button 1 'Build the tower'.

UIAlertview shown with "Do you want to do this, it takes time"

User clicks "YES":
Now I am in the alertview Delegate method.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

if (buttonIndex == 1) {//Yes the user wants to do this
 //Show activity indicator here

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [alertView addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator release];

//
[SimpleFunctions doThatMethodThatTakesALongTime];
 //remove activity indicator here

    }

}
```

Here, I want to show an activity indicator before the 'big processing' is done.

The examples of adding an activity indicator to alertview show how to add the indicator to the above alertview. But I don't want that indicator to show up, until the user has clicked on 'YES'. 
Any pointers on how that can be achieved would be great. I hope I made the question clear, please let me know if not,

Thanks

Comment: do you want to show the activity indicator on your first alert or when you click on the alert and it comes in delegate... it's little bit confusing make more clear of your question

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I want the activity indicator to show up only when the user presses yes in the alert - not in the first alert. I shall edit my question with Parentheses to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alert view reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html

In the delegate method `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` you can add things to the alertView there.

E.g.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    UIActivityIndicator * ai = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [alertView addSubview:activityIndicator];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(80, 0, 30, 30);
    [ai startAnimating];
}
```

You want to add `ai` as a ivar (class variable) in order to remove it later.

`[self.ai removeFromSuperview];`

Hope this helps.

Edit: one thing to keep in mind is that this way you will probably have to manage dismissing of your alert view yourself. You can use the method `- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated` on the alert view to dismiss it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, however, if I add the activity indicator just before that big method, it shows up only after the method is completely executed. It does not show up immediately, because I guess that processing just continues to the next step when you add a subview. It finishes that step and then shows the activity indicator, but it is of no use to me like that. Hope its clear.

Comment: Oh right, I remember this. You need to run your process in another thread, so that the Activity indicator can run in the UI thread.

Comment: The answer to this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879582/activity-indicator-not-start-animating-when-the-view-controller-is-navigate-to-a

Comment: Just to clarify. What happens is that everything that happens on the screen is run in the main thread (referred to as the UI thread). When you're programming "normally" you're using the UI thread. Your method which takes a while will "block" the UI thread, stopping the indicator from animating (or potentially showing at all). You need to make a new thread to run your calculations in so that the UI thread doesn't get blocked and your activity indicator will work fine. Hope this helps dude.

Comment: yes, I think the thread will solve it, thanks, let me try it out

Comment: running it on a background thread solved the issue...cannot upvote as I am new...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

if (buttonIndex == 1) {//Yes the user wants to do this
 UIActivityIndicatorView *loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];   
loading.frame=CGRectMake(150, 150, 16, 16);
[YOURAlertView addSubview:loading];
[SimpleFunctions doThatMethodThatTakesALongTime];
[self performSelector:@selector(turnOff:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

    }
}

-(void) turnOff {
[loading removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use according to you in your delegate and make a tag to identify different different alert...

UIAlertview *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading" message:@"Your Message"
                                        delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:nil
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];

```
 UIActivityIndicatorView *loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
            initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];   
 loading.frame=CGPointMake(myAlertView .bounds.size.width / 2, myAlertView .bounds.size.height - 40);
 [myAlertView addSubview:loading];
 [loading release];
 [myAlertView show];
```

may this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Using the `AlertView`'s bounds to layout the activity Indicator is a good idea, but be aware, that the `AlertView`'s bounds are all zero before `[alertView show]` is called.